# Using TwiML to determine when outbound call is answered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm building a TwiML Application (Twilio Mark Up Language App) that is set to call a user. When I make an outbound call & when the call ends, my server receives the appropriate callback from the Twilio API. But when the end user answers the phone however, my server does not receive a response from Twilio's server. Here's what's on my server:

```
response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
  r.Dial :callerId => our_number, :action => "/twilio/callback_response", :method => "POST", :statusCallbackEvent => ["answered"] do |d|
      # d.Number(CGI::escapeHTML number)
      d.Number("+1xxxxxxx")
      d.Number("+1xxxxxxx")
  end
end
```

It seems the `:statusCallbackEvent` parameter isn't working as expected.

My server is written in Rails 4.1.6 (Ruby 2.1.3). I'm using the 'twilio-ruby' gem. My Gemfile has `gem 'twilio-ruby, '4.2.0'` which is the most recent version of the gem.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't set status callbacks on a call using TwiML and the `<Dial>` verb.

If you are making the outbound call yourself, you can [set the `statusCallbackEvent` parameter in the initial REST API call, as described in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional).